# Can exterior parts from a mazda premacy diesel be installed on a feul one?

Tags: mazda, accident, exterior

I have had an accident with my mazda premacy 2004 CP 2.0 131 PS and damaged the front. I need new Lights and the front bumper. Have found someone selling parts from his 2.0 diesel and was not sure if they fit mine, he says they do.

How can one be sure before buying?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You'd have to do the research, but if it's from the same year and it's nothing special beyond the engine, I'd bet there's pretty good odds they new (to you) parts would fit just fine. And of course the seller *always* states they'll fit, so don't blame you checking first!

Comment: Some sellers will give good and correct advice. Others will be slightly more cautious and say “they should fit” and may even offer that you can return them. Obviously experience of sellers can be different.

Comment: They are not from the same year, his car is built in 2002, I wonder if there is some database somewhere that can tell that a certain bumper can be used on a certain set of cars